# using assign instead of subscribe in kafka consumer side

Tags: apache-kafka

When I have 1000 of web server and all are interested in messages from a topic. I am thinking of writing a specific data to a particular partition of a topic and 1000+ servers are interest in the data in that particular partition. How good is to implement assign instead of subscribe. How scalable is this approach is. can I assign 1000+ consumer to read data from a particular partition.

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka, every consumer belongs to a consumer group. When a Kafka producer sends a message to a particular group, the records of a partition are being delivered to a single consumer.

If the number of partitions is greater than the number of consumers, then some consumers will consume data from more than one partition. On the other hand, if the number of consumers is greater than the number of partitions, some consumers will be inactive as they will receive no data.

You cannot have multiple consumers -within the same consumer group- consuming data from a single partition. Therefore, in order to consume data from the same partition using N consumers, you'd need to create N distinct consumer groups too.

Note that partitioning enhances the parallelism within a Kafka cluster. If you create thousands of consumers to consume data from only one partition, I suspect that you will lose some level of parallelism. 



**Subscribe vs Assign**

*Subscribe* makes use of the consumer group; Kafka coordinator sends assignment to a consumer and the partitions of the topics subscribed to, will be distributed to the instances within that group.

*Assign* forces assignment to a list of topics.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Suppose I am using subscribe, i have a use case when a kafka consumer group instance restart and its consumer group.id is changing in each restart. Is it fine to have this behaviour or will it impact kafka performance as each server/instance restart will have a new group.id and it will read the message from begging that is also fine but my worry is what will happens to to the old group.id which are not in use will unused group.id s create any impact on memry? here i will have 1000+ server instance each having a consumer group.

Comment: Bascially, the offsets for old consumer groups will be stored. You can discard old consumer groups  using `kafka-consumer-groups --zookeeper localhost:2181 --delete --group <group-name>` if you don't need them anymore although there shouldn't be any significant impact by having a lot of consumer groups.

Comment: Is there is time that an idle consumer group can be there in the broker if it is not used for long time. Or when the idle consumer group.id removed? What is the least value that we can provide for 'log.retention.ms' config.